# Photoshop Action Double Canvas Size

Tags: photoshop

Is it possible to make an Photoshop action to make canvas height double the original height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. All you need to do is start recording an action, go to Image menu->Canvas, set it for 200%, 200% (click the dropdown to select percents from the list instead of inches, pixels, etc.) and where you want the original image to be placed. Stop recording and now you have it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm, little side question is it possible to make same with move command. If i just drag it records in pixels but can i do it relatively to height which can vary.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I'm not sure I understand what you're looking to do with the move tool. You wanting to do specific positioning after the canvas resize event? Like creating a fake matte where the picture is offset? If so, this might help: http://scottkelby.com/2010/photoshop-frame-tutorial/